# Apached + Siteminder issue

Tags: apache-2.4, single-sign-on

I am experiencing some very slow longin issue in my server that provide a single sign-on via Siteminder.

After looking at the log. I can see the following:

> [15/Dec/2015:16:47:09] [Info] [CA WebAgent IPC] [2812]
> [CSmIpcEvent::WaitForEvent] Time-out interval elapsed, but the event's
> state is nonsignaled
>
> [15/Dec/2015:16:47:25] [Info] [CA WebAgent IPC]
> [2812] [CSmIpcEvent::WaitForEvent] Time-out interval elapsed, but the
> event's state is nonsignaled
>
> [15/Dec/2015:16:47:25] [Info] [CA WebAgent IPC] [2812] [CSmIpcEvent::WaitForEvent] Time-out interval
> elapsed, but the event's state is nonsignaled
>
> [15/Dec/2015:16:47:40]

I found a huge amount of it

Does that means anything to anyone ?

Best,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is information logs, so you can safly ignore them, but logs can slow application due to their amout, so you need to increase log level to ignore them.

Restrict IPC Semaphore-Related Message Output to the Apache Error Log :

- By default the Apache Web Agent logs all levels (informational and error) of IPC semaphore-related messages to the Apache error log, regardless of the configured Apache logging level.
- To restrict the verbosity of Web Agent IPC semaphore-related output to the Apache error log, add the following parameter in the trace.conf file located in web_agent_home/config: nete.stderr.loglevel.
- [nete.stderr.loglevel] Specifies the level of IPC semaphore-related messages the Web Agent logs to the Apache error log. Accepts the following values:

  > off : The Web Agent logs no IPC semaphore-related messages to the Apache error log.
  >
  > error : The Web Agent logs only IPC semaphore-related error messages to the Apache error log.
  >
  > info : (Default) The Web Agent logs IPC semaphore-related error and informational messages to the Apache error log.

Example: Define the nete.stderr.loglevel parameter in trace.conf 
In the following snippet from trace.conf, the nete.stderr.loglevel parameter is configured to restrict the Web Agent to log only IPC semaphore-related error messages to the Apache error log:

```
CA Web Agent IPC logging levels 
nete.stderr.loglevel=error
```

Source : https://communities.ca.com/thread/116109608

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However how about if i want to understanding what is happening between The Web Agent and the server policy. I want to know what is causing problem, so i want to know the detailed. Whenever the signle sign-on is slow, i want to know, what apached is doing, what the Web agent is doing. I want to know in detailed, to understand why it is happening. I don't know how to set up the logs in the webagent apart from what you post. Do you have a doc on the matter, or could you completement your answer ?